# Best javascript compressor/compiler/obfuscator?

Tags: javascript

#### Duplicate:

> - [Are there any Javascript static analysis tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534601/are-there-any-javascript-static-analysis-tools)
> - [Which javascript minification library produces better results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360818/which-javascript-minification-library-produces-better-results)
> - [Best javascript compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932/best-javascript-compressor)
> - [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)
> - [What is the best javascript obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522064/what-is-the-best-javascript-obfuscator)
> - others (just search SO)

---

They should perform the following functionalities:
 - checking for errors
 - optimize the code
 - removing unused code
 - packaging management
 - compress it (rename varialbe and property name to shorter ones)
 - obfuscate it (sometime it is the same as compress it.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say [Yahoo's YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). I have used it for a while now and really like it. Of course once I found one I liked I stopped looking.

[javaflight](http://code.google.com/p/javaflight-code/) is also worth checking out, its an ant task for the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).