# JavaScript compression

Tags: javascript, compression

I look for tool which can compress JavaScript source code. I found some web tools which only deletes whitespace chars? But maybe exist  better tool which can compress user's function names, field name, deletes unused fields, others.

Comment: There's very little purpose in compression or obfuscating JavaScript. What you describe would likely save you a few KB per user at best and not make it much more difficult to read the code. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Multi Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883184/ways-to-compress-minify-javascript-files

Comment: I would do it, because 1)reduce the size of *.js files, 2)dotfuscate source code

Comment: Also consider using google's http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tool often used to compress JS code is the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Considering there is this option :

```
--nomunge
    Minify only. Do not obfuscate local symbols.
```

It should be able to do what you asked.

And here is an article about it : [Introducing the YUI Compressor](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/08/11/).

Quoting that article :

> It starts by analyzing the source
>   JavaScript file to understand how it
>   is structured. It then prints out the
>   token stream, replacing all local
>   symbols by a 1 (or 2, or 3) letter
>   symbol wherever such a substitution is
>   appropriate

As a sidenote : don't forget to gzip your JS/CSS files, when serving them from your webserver : this will reduce the size of data that goes through the network quite a lot !

For instance, if you are using Apache, take a look at [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), there is also [ESC](http://www.saltstorm.net/depo/esc/), but I suspect YUI is a bit better. Up to you to test.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript minimizer have been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932/best-javascript-compressor) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787977/best-javascript-compressor-compiler-obfuscator) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599911/what-do-you-use-to-minimize-and-compress-javascript-libraries), but still I feel that [the JavaScript compressor rater](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/) web page summarizes them best:

> - [JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) is a conservative compressor, written several years ago
>     by Douglas Crockford. It is considered
>     safe (especially if you verify your
>     code with JSLint first-- an excellent
>     thing to do anyway) because it doesn't
>     attempt to change any variable names.
> - Dojo [shrinksafe](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/) is a very popular Java based JavaScript
>     compressor that parses the JavaScript
>     using the rhino library and crunches
>     local variable names.
> - [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) (Version 3.1) by Dean Edwards, is also a very popular
>     JavaScript compressor, that can go
>     beyond regular compression and also
>     add advanced on-the-fly decompression
>     with a JavaScript runtime piece.
> - the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) (Version 2.4.2) is a newer compressor written by Julien Lecomte, that aims to
>     combine the safety of JSMin with the
>     higher compression levels acheived by
>     Dojo Shrinksafe. Like Dojo shrinksafe,
>     it is written in Java and based on the
>     rhino library.