# How can I compact/minimize/pack my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you use to minimize and compress JavaScript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599911/what-do-you-use-to-minimize-and-compress-javascript-libraries)

Sometimes you'll see two different files like "jquery.1.3.2.js" and "jquery.1.3.2-min.js".  The "min" version has all the whitespace and comments removed.

Is there a tool that will do that for me or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599911/what-do-you-use-to-minimize-and-compress-javascript-libraries

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883184/ways-to-compress-minify-javascript-files-closed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  The term you're looking for is "minify" your javascript.

[Jsmin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html), [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), and [ShrinkSafe](http://dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe) are all good tools.  But the leader is [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Comment: I wouldn't use packer anymore, as there is a cost in unpacking on every page load.

Comment: @Nosredna, I wish people would stop saying this about packer. It is a perfectly good minimiser. You don't have to use the base62 option, in fact it is turned off by default. It seems that people are happy to regurgitate opinions without checking the facts.

Comment: Packer with base62 option enabled is excellent if you can't serve your assets gzipped. Typically I see packer shaving an extra 30% over typical minifiers. However, I've found base62-packed files don't gzip as well. For this reason I typically use more typical minification and gzip.

EDIT: Just realised I have replied to a 6-year old thread.

EDIT2: Just noticed Dean Edwards comment. Maybe I should go to bed.

Answer (score 4):

There are several tool available to do this. Just to name a few:

- [JsMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
- [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/)
- [YUI Comporessor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34488)

Answer (score 3):

here is one way: [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Answer (score 3):

The two most popular solutions are [JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) and [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and Google has recently released its [Closure Comiler](http://code.google.com/closure/) however, the latter tends to [fail with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691861/jquery-compiled-with-google-closure-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

In order to minify your Javascript code, you can use [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) as recommended by Yahoo (http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_8.html)