# How to compress javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

Hi,

I want to compress a JavaScript code but not just to remove whitespaces also I want to change all variable names to unintelligible names. How can I provide this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Side-note: *What you want to achieve is called obfuscation.*

Comment: In my opinion this is not a duplicate question. In this case the questioner does not know about the concept of `obfuscation` and hence put his question in another way. Even though, the solution to both questions is the same.

Comment: @Ozair: Then it would still be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883184/ways-to-compress-minify-javascript-files

Comment: @Ozair: Marking a question as a duplicate isn't dunning the person asking the duplicate (at least, not unless it's really blatant that the user has just completely not made any search effort at all), it's just about not having a lot of duplication on the site.

Comment: [Online JavaScript Compressor Tool](https://compressjavascript.com/). It uses UglifyJS3 which is considered one of the best minifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add a bit http://code.google.com/closure/ can also be used

Answer (score 1):

Compressing is one thing, and the process of changing variable names to unintelligible names is called [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). For that, you will need to use a javascript obfuscator or [yuicompressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) which does both.

Similar question(s) on SO.

1. [How can I obfuscate javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

Answer (score 0):

O[nline Javascript compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following will serve you well:

http://code.google.com/closure/ and 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite fine with [yuicompressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) that obfuscate also

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

http://jscompress.com/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you tried googling it but this what i use:

[Javascript Compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

It is a good idea to have your code pass in [JSLINT](http://www.jslint.com) first to assure it works

Comment: Be aware that such online tools can inject malware into your code

Answer (score 0):

Or [Uglify](https://github.com/benjamn/cl-uglify-js), an alternative to YUI compressor that requires node.js.

Answer (score -1):

That is called obfuscation. [Check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)