# Adding external JS and CSS file dramatically slows the loading of the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

a few line like these:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_base.css" type="text/css" />`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="fallings.js"></script>`

dramatically slows my site loading down. This checks the files too?

Comment: This question cannot be answered. It is totally localized

Comment: if downloading external resources is expensive try concat-minifying them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those references could be indeed slowing load times of the page if they are, for instance, referencing other external resources. Use a profiler to detect what is slowing down load times.

There's a nice addon for Firefox called [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/ca/firefox/addon/yslow/?src=collection&collection_id=d7b5de88-dc94-748b-ea64-37ae3d3be45a) that might help you in this matter.

Here you can find different tools that may also help you determining what is slowing down your page: [7 Tools To Optimize The Speed of Your Website](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/7-tools-to-optimize-the-speed-of-your-website/)

If you're having performace issues on account of referencing external resources, put them in your web app if possible. And [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) your javascript/css resources (at least in production) if they are large. Here's a minification-related SO question that can help you [Ways to compress/minify javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/883184/851811)

Answer (score 0):

If you put your external js at the bottom of the page (just before you close the body tag) it can help the *perceived* speed of the page load. Your html, css, and images will load before the javascript executes, so if it's your js taking the extra time the page will have at least rendered.

Depending on the size of your external files and how well your js is written we could probably help you more, but we'd need to see your code.